# unable to transfer unix executable file to target folder

Tags: maven, unix, maven-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I can use maven-resources-plugin to copy resource files from source to target successfully. But problem happens while copying unix executable sh files. It's unix executable file under my resources and executed successfully when I double click it. But, after executing "mvn clean package" , it is transferred as a text file rather than unix executable file. I do no understand the main reason behind it. I tried to transfer it as a unix executable file(as in main project) in the target folder , but I could not find a way how to do it. I am also not sure if the problem is about maven-resources-plugin or with the file itself. You can see the content of the file and my plugin configuration below. Thank for your helps.

```
        <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <delimiters>
                   <delimiter>${resource.delimiter}</delimiter>
               </delimiters>
               <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>copy-resources</id>
                   <phase>compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                       <resources>
                           <!-- Include filtered resources and Dockerfile
                               for docker and packaging installation tests -->
                           <resource>
                               <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/filter</directory>
                               <filtering>true</filtering>
                           </resource>
                           <resource>
                               <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                               <filtering>true</filtering>
                               <includes>
                                   <include>application.yml</include>
                                   <include>logback.xml</include>
                               </includes>
                           </resource>
                        </resources>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
```

Content of the unix executable bash file :

```
          #!/bin/bash
    # 

    httpd Startup script for the Apache HTTP Server

   # chkconfig: - 85 15
   # description: Apache is a World Wide Web server.  It is used to serve \
#          HTML files and CGI.
# processname: httpd
# config: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
# config: /etc/sysconfig/httpd
# pidfile: /var/run/httpd.pid

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/httpd ]; then
        . /etc/sysconfig/httpd
fi

# Start httpd in the C locale by default.
HTTPD_LANG=${HTTPD_LANG-"C"}

# This will prevent initlog from swallowing up a pass-phrase prompt if
# mod_ssl needs a pass-phrase from the user.
INITLOG_ARGS=""

# Set HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker in /etc/sysconfig/httpd to use a server
# with the thread-based "worker" MPM; BE WARNED that some modules may not
# work correctly with a thread-based MPM; notably PHP will refuse to start.

# Path to the apachectl script, server binary, and short-form for messages.
apachectl=/usr/sbin/apachectl
httpd=${HTTPD-/usr/sbin/httpd}
prog=httpd
pidfile=${PIDFILE-/var/run/httpd.pid}
lockfile=${LOCKFILE-/var/lock/subsys/httpd}
RETVAL=0

# check for 1.3 configuration
check13 () {
    CONFFILE=/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    GONE="(ServerType|BindAddress|Port|AddModule|ClearModuleList|"
    GONE="${GONE}AgentLog|RefererLog|RefererIgnore|FancyIndexing|"
    GONE="${GONE}AccessConfig|ResourceConfig)"
    if LANG=C grep -Eiq "^[[:space:]]*($GONE)" $CONFFILE; then
        echo
        echo 1>&2 " Apache 1.3 configuration directives found"
        echo 1>&2 " please read /usr/share/doc/httpd-2.2.3/migration.html"
        failure "Apache 1.3 config directives test"
        echo
        exit 1
    fi
}

# The semantics of these two functions differ from the way apachectl does
# things -- attempting to start while running is a failure, and shutdown
# when not running is also a failure.  So we just do it the way init scripts
# are expected to behave here.
start() {
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        check13 || exit 1
        LANG=$HTTPD_LANG daemon --pidfile=${pidfile} $httpd $OPTIONS
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch ${lockfile}
        return $RETVAL
}

# When stopping httpd a delay of >10 second is required before SIGKILLing the
# httpd parent; this gives enough time for the httpd parent to SIGKILL any
# errant children.
stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc -p ${pidfile} -d 10 $httpd
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f ${lockfile} ${pidfile}
}
reload() {
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
    if ! LANG=$HTTPD_LANG $httpd $OPTIONS -t >&/dev/null; then
        RETVAL=$?
        echo $"not reloading due to configuration syntax error"
        failure $"not reloading $httpd due to configuration syntax error"
    else
        killproc -p ${pidfile} $httpd -HUP
        RETVAL=$?
    fi
    echo
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  status)
        status -p ${pidfile} $httpd
    RETVAL=$?
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  condrestart)
    if [ -f ${pidfile} ] ; then
        stop
        start
    fi
    ;;
  reload)
        reload
    ;;
  graceful|help|configtest|fullstatus)
    $apachectl $@
    RETVAL=$?
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $prog {start|stop|restart|condrestart|reload|status|fullstatus|graceful|help|configtest}"
    exit 1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why are you copying an httpd start file (shell) with Maven?

Comment: hello @khmarbaise yes after copying the file I use rpm-maven-plugin to get the resources from the target folder and create a rpm file.Unfortunately, the plugin is able to copy the files from the target folder and it created the rpm file. But as expected in the content of the rpm file, there is an sh file instead of a unix executable(shell) file.

Comment: You have to correctly set the executable flag in the rpm-maven-plugin configuration to handle that correctly. Apart from that your configuration looks to complicated for the task...

Comment: @khmarbaise so you believe that nothing to do with the maven-resource-plugin as the executable flag should be given in the rpm-maven-plugin. Do you know the flag for that ?

Comment: I do not believe. I know that you have to do it that way https://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/map-params.html#filemode Also you can make the configuration easier than the long configuration for maven-resources-plugin.

Comment: I don't understand why you are creating an RPM for httpd server where a rpm already exists for and why via Maven? Does not make sense for me?

Comment: @khmarbaise the business requirements :) They wanted to create it via Maven

Comment: Whoever they are...it does not make sense (wasting time) recreate things which already exists in every yum/rpm repository...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following and just configure the filtering for a directory of your [choice via](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html):

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/filter</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
  ...
</resources>
```

In rpm maven plugin you can use the following:

```
<mapping>
  <directory>/xyz/sbin/</directory>
  <filemode>755</filemode>
  <username>user</username>
  <groupname>group</groupname>
  <sources>
    <source>
      <location>${project.build.directory}/xyz.sh</location>
    </source>
  </sources>
</mapping>
```

The `${project.build.directory}` will be the `target` directory.

Comment: that's perfectly solved my problem. I didn't  know that problem was coming from the rights . Thank you @khmarbaise